# Pass values from view, as input values to form in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a view which calls a child action:

```
@Html.Action("RenderPostMessage", "JobSurface")
```

The controller is like this:

```
public ActionResult RenderPostMessage()
{
    PostMessageViewModel postMessageViewModel = new PostMessageViewModel();
    return PartialView("PostMessage", postMessageViewModel);
}
```

The partial this calls is like this:

```
@model PostMessageViewModel

@{
    Html.EnableClientValidation(true);
    Html.EnableUnobtrusiveJavaScript(true);
}
@using (Html.BeginUmbracoForm<JobSurfaceController>("HandlePostMessage", new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)       

    <p>
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Message)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Message)
    </p>

    <p>
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.File)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.File, new { type = "file" })
    </p>
    <p><button class="button">Post Message</button></p>
}
```

The 'handle post message' controller is like this:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult HandlePostMessage(PostMessageViewModel model)
{
    // Some logic
}
```

I have a bunch of variables in the view that I need to somehow pass in to the form (as hidden input fields perhaps?) but although I know how to create hidden inputs on the partial, I've no idea how to populate them with the values from the view.

Could anyone suggest how to get the value passed through to the controller?

Many thanks.

Comment: `@Html.Action("RenderPostMessage"...` but your ActionResult signature is HandlePostMessage (is this just a typo?).  Since you have a view model, why not just just add `test` as a public property of the view model?

Comment: Thanks @Stephen. I'm a noob at MVC so still trying to get my head around this. I think it may be a bit more complicated, so I'll update my original post with more details.

Comment: You asked to "populate [the variables] with the values from the view", but you accepted the answer that populates the variables from the controller.  Why?

Also, since you have a 'PostMessageViewModel', why would you ever venture into dynamic territory by using the ViewBag...simply make them properties on PostMessageViewModel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have a bunch of variables in the view that I need to somehow pass in
>   to the form (as hidden input fields perhaps?)

It's simple, if you want to render a hidden input field with a value then add it to the `ViewBag` object in the view.

For instance, if you want to add the content of a variable to the form then in the view you do this:

`ViewBag.Foo = "Some Value";`

Then in the cshtml file you add the hidden field:

`@Html.Hidden("Foo")`

This way you will receive the value in the form post.

**EDIT: this is how your code should look.**

```
public ActionResult RenderPostMessage()
{
    PostMessageViewModel postMessageViewModel = new PostMessageViewModel();

    // here you set as many values as you want to receive in the form post.
    ViewBag.SomeField = "Some Value";

    return PartialView("PostMessage", postMessageViewModel);
}
```

**View**

```
@model PostMessageViewModel

@{
    Html.EnableClientValidation(true);
    Html.EnableUnobtrusiveJavaScript(true);
}
@using (Html.BeginUmbracoForm<JobSurfaceController>("HandlePostMessage", new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)       

    @Html.Hidden("SomeField")

    <p>
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Message)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Message)
    </p>

    <p>
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.File)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.File, new { type = "file" })
    </p>
    <p><button class="button">Post Message</button></p>
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this.  I now see that a hidden input is created with `name="Foo"` attribute, but it doesn't contain a value (when I view in browser dev tools).  Should it?  Once I know for sure then I can move forward to try to get the value in the code and put it to use.

Comment: @Dan did you set the value in the `Viewbag`. You need to set the value  you want in the hidden field.

Answer (score 1):

`@Html.Action` has a parameter 'routeValues' which is an anonymous object.  You can pass values there.  So...from view to action:

```
@Html.Action("RenderPostMessage", routeValues:new{SurfaceType = "JobSurface", OtherValue = "Something", NewValue = "Something else"});
```

Action accepts these route values as method parameters:

```
    public ActionResult RenderPostMessage(string surfaceType, string otherValue, string newValue)
    {
        var viewModel = new PostMessageViewModel();
viewModel.SurfaceType = surfaceType;
viewModel.OtherValue = otherValue;
viewModel.NewValue = newValue;
        return PartialView("PostMessage", viewModel);
    }
```

Done!